# TypeError for dictionaries: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am a new starter in python domain, I am having

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

The code is below. I have to get the list from dictionary. Can anyone help me to clear the concept. Thanks

```
ds = {'A': ['1', '3', '2', '5', '6'], 'B': ['1', '3', '2', '5'], 'C': ['3', '6', '8', '9', '7']} 

def analysis():
  lists = ds["A"]
  length = len(lists)
  print(lists)
  print(length)
  total = sum(lists)
  print(total)
 
analysis()
```

Comment: The elements in `ds["A"]` are string, you need to convert it to int.So you could use `total = sum(map(int, lists))`.

Answer (score 1):

Your values inside the list are stored as strings. You need to convert them to integers inorder to do the sum operation:

```
ds = {'A': ['1', '3', '2', '5', '6'], 'B': ['1', '3', '2', '5'], 'C': ['3', '6', '8', '9', '7']} 

def analysis():
  lists = list(map(int,ds["A"])) #Conversion to integer
  length = len(lists)
  print(lists)
  print(length)
  total = sum(lists)
  print(total)
 
analysis()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is to sum up all the **numbers** in your dict, instead of concating them.

So the problem is, the "numbers" in your dict are `str`, not `int`. As what error message told you, these two types cannot add together. The workaround is very simple, just firstly convert them into `int`.

```py
total = sum(map(int, lists))
```

Answer (score 0):

ds = {'A': ['1', '3', '2', '5', '6'], 'B': ['1', '3', '2', '5'], 'C': ['3', '6', '8', '9', '7']}

ds["A"] gives list of string
sum(list) requires list to have numeric value and not string

you can map list before to convert string to intger
sum(map(int,list))